# Why this difference occurred?

Tags: html, css

I want to make div that appears like `navbar` in bootstrap's.

I made two div and collocated in two ways.

First, I located divOneGray first and then divTwoBlue like,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="divGray">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="background-color: #cccccc; height: 4000px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="divBlue">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="background-color: #003366; height: 100px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, `divBlue` appears above `divGray`,

But Second case,

```
 <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row" id="divBlue">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="background-color: #003366; height: 100px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="divGray">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="background-color: #cccccc; height: 4000px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`divGray` appears above `divBlue`.

Why this happened?

What is needed to do it like First case without collocating of html code?

**EDIT:**
Here is my hoping result: 
https://jsfiddle.net/d6wunt0L/

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of bootstrap navbar, and also use something like JSFiddle, so we can run and see the problems. It'll help others give you answers in a timely fashion if you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second case, after rendering `divBlue` you have render `divGrey` which overlaps the `divBlue`, so **to show the `divBlue` you need to apply `z-index:1` for `divBlue`** whereas in your first case, you are rendering `blueDiv` after  `greyDiv`, so you don't find any problem here.

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
 <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row" id="divBlue">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="background-color: #003366; height: 100px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px;z-index:1;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="divGray">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="background-color: #cccccc; height: 4000px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, pawan Kumar

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="divGray">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #cccccc; height: 4000px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="divBlue">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #003366; height: 100px; bottom: 0px;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```